# Is it possible to pass a condition to an Oracle user-defined function?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-functions

I'm wondering if it's possibile to pass (any way is ok, also hacks) a condition (boolean) to an user-defined function in Oracle.

Let's say I want something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SCHEMA.MY_FUNC (
    condition IN ???,
    my_value IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
    IF condition THEN
        RETURN my_value + 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN my_value;
END;
```

Comment: Test the condition outside of your function, then pass 1 or 0 to the function?

Comment: @PeterLang I cannot use BOOLEAN in plain SQL context, then.

Comment: @lorenzo-s: That's the information that I was missing in your post. What exactly is the problem that you try to solve, why do you need this?

Comment: @PeterLang I was simply searching for something less verbose than `CASE WHEN [some complex condition] THEN 1 ELSE 0`, for passing some "flags" to some functions, that's all. Anyway, it seems I have no chance but using CASE or passing each term of the condition to the function itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to be able to call it from plain SQL - otherwise you could just use a `BOOLEAN` - you can pass a fixed value and interpret that instead. 0/1, Y/N etc are common; using 1 as true (and anything else as false) for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FUNC (
    condition IN NUMBER,
    my_value IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
    IF condition = 1 THEN
        RETURN my_value + 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN my_value;
END;
/

FUNCTION MY_FUNC compiled

select my_func(0, 42) from dual;
select my_func(1, 42) from dual;

MY_FUNC(0,42)
-------------
           42 

MY_FUNC(1,42)
-------------
           43
```

---

If you can pass the expression as a string, say, you could hack something together with dynamic SQL I suppose:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func (
    condition IN varchar2,
    my_value IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    boolstr VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT CASE WHEN ' || condition
        || ' THEN ''true'' ELSE ''false'' END FROM dual' INTO boolstr;
    IF boolstr = 'true' THEN
        RETURN my_value + 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN my_value;
END;
/
```

Which you'd have to call like:

```
select my_func('1=1', 42) from dual;
```

So you'd have to build your condition up into a string, like:

```
select my_func(a ||'='|| b, 42) from <some table with a and b columns>;
```

This seems rather unwieldy, and allows almost anything to be passed as a condition, which may of course be dangerous (SQL injection possibilities, to put it mildly). If only certain 'conditions' as possible it might be better to have function wrappers that take simple arguments and figure out the boolean condition value to call the real function, so you'd call something like `my_func_eq(42, a, b)`.

I'd also consider whether a function is really necessary - depending on what the function is doing of course, you can probably achieve the same effect in a simple query, e.g. with case statements.

Comment: No chance to use condition directly like `SELECT my_func(a = b)` or something that is not `SELECT my_func(CASE WHEN a = b THEN 1 ELSE 0)`? Sorry, I'm new to Oracle... *PS: what is the `/` symbol after function creation? I see it also on Oracle doc, but I can't get it, I did not used during my tests...*

Comment: @loernzo-s - I've added a version that shows it's possible to pass a string to be evaluated as a condition, but being possible doesn't necessarily make it a good idea. As Peter suggests, please expand on what you're really trying to do, and why you think this construct is needed.

Comment: Also... you need the `/` to get the PL/SQL block - in this case the function creation - to be executed, at least when running it from SQL*Plus or SQL Developer. If you have it in a script and it's the last thing it'll execute anyway, but it's normally needed so it's better to always use it to avoid confusion.

Comment: I was simply searching for something less verbose than `CASE WHEN [some complex condition] THEN 1 ELSE 0`, for passing some "flags" to some functions, that's all. Anyway, it seems I have no chance but using CASE or passing each term of the condition to the function itself.

Comment: `+1`: If really necessary, then I think I'd change your code to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT CASE WHEN ' || condition || ' THEN ''true'' ELSE ''false'' END FROM dual'`. This would still evaluate the condition, but restrict executing dangerous code as condition.

Comment: @Peter Lang - thanks, that's much better; not sure why I made it so complicated!